# JSP custom tag ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, custom-tag

I'm trying to use the following class in a JSP-based custom tag:

```
public class HelloWorldTest {
    public void hello1() { }
}
```

The tag file is in `WEB-INF/tags/hello.tag`:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<% HelloWorldTest hello; %>
```

I'm trying to use the tag from `index.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="my"%&gt;
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %&gt;
<html>
  <body>
    <my:hello></my:hello>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:178)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

The problem is trying to use the `HelloWorldTest` class, because a tag without it works fine:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<% for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
  <%= i %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Where are you importing packages in your code?

Comment: thank you, i replaced HelloWorldTest to src/mypackage/ and added `code <%@ tag import="mypackage.HelloWorldTest" %>` to hello.tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually [import the class](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm7.html) with an `import` directive.

```
<%@ page import="my.package.HelloWorld" %>
```

(Where `my.package` is replaced with your class's actual package.)